# Auto switch desktops Windows, 10 Like a slideshow

Tags: windows-10, monitoring, gui

I have a big screen that shows several monitoring applications but lacks enough to show all applications clearly on one desktop.  Is there a way to make use of Windows 10 multi desktops and get it auto switch between these desktops periodically.

Comment: I can only think to try an automatic mouse clicker or key presser, though I would not know which to suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried AutoIT? It's a scripting language designed for automating the Windows GUI and general scripting. 
Fairly simple to use.

Comment: Please read [How to recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for **minimum required information** and suggestions on how to recommend software on Super User.  To keep your answer useful even if the provided link(s) breaks these details should be edited into your answer.